TypeError: contentRefs[(info & binary.BITS5)] is not a function while applying update to Y.Doc
I'm working on a collaborative real-time document editor using Yjs, and I'm encountering the following error when trying to apply a Yjs update from a saved state in MongoDB:
Background:
I have implemented a WebSocket server that connects multiple clients to share document changes in real time. The Y.Doc is being serialized and saved to MongoDB, and later deserialized when a client connects.
Here’s the relevant code for saving and loading the Y.Doc:
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { setupWSConnection } from 'y-websocket/bin/utils';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Room from './models/Room.js';  // Room schema for MongoDB
import * as Y from 'yjs';
import url from 'url'; // Parse query strings
import Connection from './db.js';

// Connect to MongoDB
Connection();

// Store active rooms in memory
const activeRooms = {};

// Function to save the Y.Doc to MongoDB
async function saveYDocToDB(roomName, ydoc) {
    try {
        // Serialize the entire Y.Doc into a state Uint8Array
        const ydocState = Y.encodeStateAsUpdate(ydoc);
        console.log("yDocState", ydocState);

        // Convert the Uint8Array into a Buffer for MongoDB storage
        const bufferState = Buffer.from(ydocState);
        console.log("bufferState", bufferState);

        // Find the room in the database
        let room = await Room.findById(roomName);

        if (room) {
            // If the room exists, update the state
            room.state = bufferState;
            await room.save();  // Save the changes to MongoDB
            console.log(`Successfully saved full Y.Doc for room ${roomName}`);
        } else {
            // If the room doesn't exist, create a new entry in the database
            await Room.create({ name: roomName, state: bufferState });
            console.log(`Created new room ${roomName} and saved full Y.Doc to DB`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving Y.Doc to DB:', error);
    }
}

// Function to load the Y.Doc from MongoDB
async function loadYDocFromDB(roomName) {
    try {
        // Fetch the room from MongoDB
        const room = await Room.findById(roomName);
        console.log("Fetched room from DB:", room);

        // Create a new Y.Doc
        const ydoc = new Y.Doc();

        if (room && room.state) {
            console.log("Room state:", room.state);

            // Ensure room.state is a Buffer and convert it correctly
            const uint8ArrayState = new Uint8Array(room.state.buffer || room.state);
            console.log("uint8ArrayState:", uint8ArrayState);

            try {
                // Apply the update to the Y.Doc
                Y.applyUpdate(ydoc, uint8ArrayState);
                console.log(`Loaded Y.Doc state for room ${roomName} from DB`);
            } catch (applyUpdateError) {
                console.error("Failed to apply update to Y.Doc:", applyUpdateError);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(`No saved state for room ${roomName} in DB, starting fresh.`);
        }

        return ydoc;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading Y.Doc from DB:', error);
        return new Y.Doc();  // Return a new Y.Doc in case of error
    }
}

// Function to handle room setup and connection
async function setupRoomConnection(ws, roomName) {
    let ydoc;
    roomName = roomName.split('/')[0]; // Handle room name from URL

    // If the room exists in memory, fetch from memory
    if (activeRooms[roomName]) {
        console.log(`Room ${roomName} found in memory`);
        ydoc = activeRooms[roomName].ydoc;
        activeRooms[roomName].users += 1; // Increment user count
    } else {
        // If the room doesn't exist in memory, fetch from MongoDB
        console.log(`Room ${roomName} not found in memory, fetching from DB`);
        ydoc = await loadYDocFromDB(roomName);  // Load the Y.Doc from the DB

        // Store the room in memory
        activeRooms[roomName] = { ydoc, users: 1 };
    }

    // Set up WebSocket connection for real-time updates
    setupWSConnection(ws, ydoc);

    // Listen to Y.Doc updates and log them
    ydoc.on('update', (update) => {
        console.log(`Update received for room ${roomName}:`, update);
    });

    // Handle WebSocket disconnection
    ws.on('close', async () => {
        // Log when users leave the room
        console.log(`User left room ${roomName}, saving Y.Doc to DB`);
        await saveYDocToDB(roomName, ydoc);  // Save the Y.Doc to the DB
        activeRooms[roomName].users -= 1; // Decrement user count
        if (activeRooms[roomName].users === 0) {
            delete activeRooms[roomName]; // Remove room if no users left
        }
    });
}

// WebSocket server setup
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 1234 });

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
    const roomName = parsedUrl.query.roomName;

    if (!roomName) {
        console.error('Room name is required');
        ws.close();
        return;
    }

    console.log(`Client connected to room: ${roomName}`);
    setupRoomConnection(ws, roomName);
});

// Handle errors globally
wss.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket server error:', error);
});

console.log('WebSocket server running on ws://localhost:1234');



and my schema is
// File: models/Room.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    state: {
        type: Buffer,  // The Yjs document state will be saved as binary data
        default: null
    }
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room2', roomSchema);
export default Room;


error i am getting is
Failed to apply update to Y.Doc: TypeError: contentRefs[(info & binary.BITS5)] is not a function 
Current Behavior:
I successfully save the Y.Doc state to MongoDB.
Upon loading the state and applying it to a new Y.Doc, I receive the TypeError.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified that the state field in MongoDB is storing the serialized Yjs state correctly.
Ensured that I'm using compatible versions of Yjs.
Added console logs to debug the state being loaded from the database.
Questions:
What could cause the TypeError: contentRefs[(info & binary.BITS5)] is not a function when applying the update?
Are there any steps I can take to ensure that the Y.Doc is properly serialized and deserialized?
How can I further debug this issue?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
